# how do I compile java files and import them with pyjnius with kivy

Tags: python-3.x, pyjnius

Before running buildozer I put a java file in `ga/chatme/web/WebHandler.java`.
Then, I set the `android.add_src` to `ga/chatme/web` but, I cant seem to import it with `autoclass('ga.chatme.web.WebHandler')`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by putting everything in an src folder then pointing `android.src` to it